# Performance hit during deserialzation of a large array

Tags: java, performance, deserialization

I am sending large arrays(>100) elements to my Java backend every second.
Spring(jackson) is converting this array and mapping it to a local `String[]`.

I can map this to a `String` value for better performance.

Is deserializing in such scenarios a major time consumption activity or not a big deal? If not, when does this become a big deal?

**So, basically I am trying to understand the difference between mapping to `String` vs `String[]`** for big values like an array of 100 elements.

FWIW, internally it is using `Jackson` parser. And I have to scale this to support concurrent users sending such serialized array data.

Comment: Do you *think* that it is slow? Or have you *tested* it?

Comment: Run a profiler and see whether it's sufficient for the amount of requests you need to handle. 'Slow' and 'fast' are relative terms.

Comment: I understand that this seems to be vague. My question was to get some insight regarding mapping to `String` vs mapping `String[]`.
I'll update the question. Also, I think it is slow, but how slow is the question.

Answer (score -1):

> Is deserializing in such scenarios a major time consumption activity or not a big deal?

That's a vague question, so it deserves a vague answer - it depends.

In some cases it could be insignificant, in others is could be a major bottleneck. It depends on your application and how often you perform this serialization/deserialization.

It's a bit like asking whether 1$ is a lot. Paying 1$ for something important once a year when you're already spending 1,000,000$ on other things is insignificant.

Paying 1$ every second when the rest of your expenses are 1$ per day is probably a lot.

If you want to improve the performance of your application, you should start by *measuring*. See what takes too much time and/or resources, and optimize that.

Comment: As mentioned, I am sending array of `~100` elements every `second`.